# Dockerfile installs Meteor globally, not locally

Tags: ubuntu, docker

My Dockerfile installs Meteor on the image. Only problem is when I log in to my non root user and run `meteor` it then begins to download and install it locally. So it recognises `meteor` as a command but it is not available immediately to run my app-code. How can I make it available to my non root user.

[image]

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# update the system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl \
    apt-utils \
    locales \
    nano \
    python

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 

# create a user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash dev
ENV HOME=/home
WORKDIR $HOME/dev

RUN chmod -R 777 ~
RUN chown -R dev: /home/dev
USER dev
```

Comment: What is the output of `which meteor` as user dev, after running your script?

Comment: @eyoung100 It is pictured in the photo, it installs it locally and then proceeds as normally but at the point where the image is being created the output is red.